# Sequelize function with in and not in where filters

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

My getData function retrieves some data, the associated users, and an array that shows who requested the data and who did not. What I want is that if req.body.sub_params = 1, it returns all elements where at least one data_status.need = 1. If req.body.sub_params = 0, it should return all data where all data_status.need = 0.

```
function getData(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.sub_params)
  const pageSize = req.body.pagedata.pageSize;
  const pageIndex = req.body.pagedata.pageIndex;
  const offset = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const limit = pageSize;

  Data.findAndCountAll({
    where: req.body.params,
   
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [
      {
        model: Users,
        as: "user_data",
        required: true,
      },
      {
        model: User_Group,
        as: "creater",
      },
      {
        model: Data_Status,
        as: "data_status",
     
         where: req.body.sub_params,
        
        include: [
          {
            model: Users,
            as: "changer_user",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
    distinct: true,
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.json({
      final_data: data.rows,
      totalItemsCount: data.count,
    });
  });
}
```

I try these:

```
{
        model: Data_Status,
        as: "data_status",
        where: {
          need: 0, // "need" értéke 0
          
          // need: {
          //   [Op.not]: 1, //
          // },
        },
```

I tried to filter the data with some()...